# Exporting a track and waypoints as GPX from QGIS

Tags: qgis, gpx

I have a point layer and a line layer in my QGIS project. How can I export them into a single GPX file with the point layer becoming waypoints (`<wpt>` elements) and the line becoming the track (`<trk>`)?